# Why doesn't debugger stop at breakpoint?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I have the problem that the chrome debugger for JS doesn't stop every time I execute one certain function. I tried debugger; and also setting breakpoints where I want the code to stop by putting a blue tag on the gutter next to the line on the left.

any ideas why this happens?

Comment: It usually means the code is not invoked.

Comment: It is difficult to determine without a reproducible test case. Can you create one and post it in your question?

Comment: Related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11788081/465053).

Comment: Tried my React app served on parcel on Firefox and it worked; tried it on Chrome v102.0.5005.115 (Official Build) and it failed. It was working on Chrome before.

Answer (score 35):

Without a clear reproduction plan, it is very hard to tell why your breakpoints are not hitting.

But, one surest way of stopping on a line is writing:

```
debugger;
```

to the location where you want to stop. Without any blue signs on the gutter, the debugger will halt.

**NOTE:** Be sure to clear all the `debugger;` when you are done with it.

**More [info is here](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console#setting_breakpoints_in_javascript)**

Comment: My chrome still ignores it and does nothing, even though I log a text with console.log before i call `debugger` and that text is getting logged.

Comment: This might be helpful if you're in a position to modify the source but in general it is not a solution to op's question.

Answer (score 19):

What I found worked was to set my breakpoints using the suggestions above, then in the extension's console run:
`location.reload(true);`

This re-opens the extensions, set off my breakpoints and allowed me to debug!

It appears that the problem is related to the debugger loading *after* the extension, thus not capturing the breakpoints. Hope that helps!

Comment: Worked for me running VS Code. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

For me this appears to be a bug in chrome - nothing would cause a breakpoint to be hit, not even `debugger`. I had to close and re-open Chrome, and then my breakpoints worked.

Answer (score 4):

I had an issue with breakpoints being hit that I just resolved.
Breakpoints within javascript in the html were not being hit, although I could set and hit breakpoints in included Javascript files.

I found that the problem was that the source file was included twice.  The base html page (not dynamically included) has the **sourceURL tag** in it.  This caused the same javascript to exist twice in the source pane, causing the issue.

I removed the "sourceURL" tag from the base html page, and breakpoint resumed working

Comment: Thsi is it. This happens when you add the working folder, containing the js to the chrome workspace after you opened the file.

Comment: Same for me. Removing file/folder from workspace fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Also, it's possible that breakpoints are disabled. You can toggle this in the debugger or by pressing Ctrl + F8

Answer (score 1):

Had you **add folder to workspace** accidentally?
If yes, your devTool breakPoint would stop work on this file.
[image]

After I **remove folder from workspace**, breakpoint feature is back!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found that code referenced by a  tag with the async property inside of it don't stop at breakpoints in developer mode.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you add your target file to blackbox, so debugger could not be triggered on it.

[image: add to blacked script]
**solve:**
[image: notice]
[image: remove blacked]

ref: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/blackboxing

Comment: It seems like this is now called [Ignore List](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67449405/1159167)

Answer (score 1):

This may sound dumb... but it worked for me... Simply closing and re-opening the browser restored JS debugging functionality.

Answer (score 0):

With client solutions like angular js, the modules and controllers are picked up independent of the file name. Most probably you would have created a backup/copy of file in the same folder as the actual file you are debugging. This might be the js file getting called instead of one you intended. You can delete that file and it should work fine.

Answer (score -1):

to test your function debug point you can call that function right from console.. it will call and hit your breakpoint

Comment: my problem is not that it won't ever stop at the breakpoint, it is that in the first run it doesn't, which is the most important..
after the first time it works perfectly fine.. but thats too late

Comment: you can set condition by right clicking on breakpoint and edit breakpoint , set condition that always evaluates to true like 1 == 1 .. check and reply

Answer (score -1):

Check if your function is called properly. For me, I resolved the problem by conceptualising the flow of my program and found out that the function calling had some errors. After figuring that out, it was easy to continue.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and it turned out that reason was that I had enabled bundle, i.e.
 in the **BundleConfig.cs** I had `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;`
When I **changed it to** `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;` it worked.......

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the VS, check if configuration is DEBUG. When is Release the MVC minify the JS.