# How can I hit breakpoints (and see error line numbers) when debugging javascript on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, debugging, android-browser

I'm trying to follow [these](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/?hl=en) instructions for debugging android javascript.

I am aware of [How can I debug javascript on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314886/how-can-i-debug-javascript-on-android), but it's not clear to me how (or if) I can hit breakpoints - either using Chrome on the Android device, or the Android browser.

I can see and 'inspect' the device OK:

[image]

But breakpoints don't get hit, nor can I see line numbers on the errors in the console:

[image]

Between these two problems, I'm not getting much useful information from the debugging experience! I have tried going to 'about:debug' in the android browser, and do see the debug options appear.

I will add that the js I am debugging works fine in the latest Chrome on the same Android device.

Comment: Are you sure that none are hitting?  The line you have marked above is on the start of a IIFE-- not sure if that would debug ever.  Also, have you tried dropping a `debugger;` statement in your code to see if the tools will break there?

Comment: @anied That line does debug in Chrome. `debugger;` is a good idea - I will try.

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788081/chrome-javascript-debugger-breakpoints-dont-do-anything

Comment: another way to check is put alert in js file and get the desired value as output in alert

Answer (score 0):

First off, it seems like there are a bunch of syntax errors that may be preventing mustache.js from executing at all - see if you can take care of those first.

I'd try setting a breakpoint on the next line down - line #9 - to see if anything in that IIFE is running at all.

Comment: This is some JS that works fine in the latest Chrome on the same device - these syntax errors only appear on the Android browser. I've tried setting breakpoints in a whole bunch of places... pretty sure I'd have hit one if they were able to be hit at all. That one is only supposed to be illustrative.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a module bundler (such as Webpack) in development (based on port 8080 in your screenshot), most likely the code you're trying to debug is executed via `eval`. In which case by the time you can see it in the devtools, it has already run.

You can either use the `debugger` statement in your code, or running in production mode - where there's a real script file being executed. In both cases, you should attach the remote debugger first, and only then navigate to your page (or refresh it).

Comment: it's just 8080 'cos that's the default port of https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

Answer (score 0):

I have now tried the same thing again, and this time didn't experience the problem. Unfortunately I can't put my finger on what the problem was exactly, as due to my dev machine dying I am running a new windows 10 installation, and potentially a different version of the Android SDK and ADB. The phone and android browser haven't changed.

Anyway, I can now set and hit breakpoints as I'd expect:

[image]

I also get better error descriptions and line numbers:

[image]

FWIW, the only problem that needed fixing was changing some 'let' declarations to 'var'.