# Preserve 'debugger' keyword grunt uglify

Tags: javascript, grunt-contrib-uglify

I'm developing a library in JS and I want to preserve 'debugger' keyword after using grunt-contrib-uglify because is intentional usage, but default behavior (obviously) is delete all debuggers.

My grunt file:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        uglify: {
            CrackerTrapProductionMinJS: {
                options:{
                    banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> - v<%= pkg.version %> - ' +
            '<%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n',
                drop_console: true,
                mangle: {
                    reserved: ['debugger']
                  }
                },
                files: {
                    './build/cracker-trap.min.js': './build/cracker-trap.ob.js'
                }
            }
        },          
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify']);
};
```

And the method that I want to preserve the debugger keyword to validate if user has developer tools opened:

```
function timeValidation() {
    var startTime = new Date();
    debugger;
    var endTime = new Date();

    return endTime - startTime > 100;
}
```

Complete code in: https://github.com/bioverflow/cracker-trap

Comment: I'm not sure if this is applicable to your setup, but in development mode, you shouldn't use uglify. Make a separate development config file to not minify code at all, and only use uglify in production

Comment: @AndyRay do you realize OP wants it to remain in prod?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you just have to specify the [`compress`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify#compress) options object inside your `grunt-contrib-uglify` setup section, and set `drop_debugger` to false as is shown [here](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#compress-options)

So your setup should be something like this:

```
uglify: {
  CrackerTrapProductionMinJS: {
    options:{
      banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> - v<%= pkg.version %> - <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n',
      drop_console: true,
      compress: {
        drop_debugger: false
      },
      files: {
        './build/cracker-trap.min.js': './build/cracker-trap.ob.js'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Though I don't have gulp running so, I cannot verify

Comment: @CamiRodriguez I updated my post and moved the compress outside the `mangle` object, I think I misread the docs, as far as uglifyjs goes that is what is on their docs

Comment: Is it possible to preserve a specific debugger statement, removing all others, similar to how you can preserve a specific comment with @preserve?

Comment: @Jools Not that I know off, I could be wrong though, maybe raise an issue on the [github page](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues)?

Comment: Thanks! ```options: {
        banner: "/*some comment*/\n",
        compress: {
          drop_debugger: false
        },
      },```

Comment: The `compress` property is a property of `options` object!

Comment: oh, you are right @RomanGrinyov, I should probably indent that a little better :)